# Github Repository

Tags: github, repository

my friend and I have been collaborating on many projects on Github which are currently private at the moment. He created those repositories and invited me to them.

My question is that once the repositories come public, will the repository be listed also under my account? (i.e will other people see it when they check out my profile)

Answer (score 0):

No, public repositories will only appear under the owner's profile page. You can, however, use GitHub's [pinned repositories](https://github.com/blog/2191-pin-repositories-to-your-github-profile) feature, which allows you to pin any public repository that you've contributed to to your profile page.